How can RxMethods be reused in SignalStore
I am using ngrx/SignalStore to manage my state for a page containing a number of components.  I provide the store on the route to this page.
By doing this I am able to use ngrx/router-store to retrieve the id of the item I'm displaying and initiate the load of the data from within the Store
  withHooks({
    onInit(store, store = inject(Store<State>)) {
      const id$ = store.select(selectRouteParam('id')).pipe(
        map((id) => (id ? parseInt(id) : null)),
        filter((id) => !!id),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        takeUntilDestroyed()
      );
      store.load(id$);
    },
  })

My load method combines data from a number of sources but is basically:
      const load = rxMethod<number>(
        pipe(
          switchMap((id: number) => myAPIService.getById(id).pipe(tapResponse({next:....

I want to create other methods in the store to perform deletesById and updatesById. These will also be RxMethods and call APIs to do the updates.  Following the API calls I want the state to refresh, essentially by calling load again (I don't have the new state locally to just update it without the API call - things like last updated timestamps) .
Would it be an antipattern to call an RxMethod from a tap operator in another rxMethod?  It doesn't feel right but not sure how else I can re-use all my logic in load?
